# Columns depending on posts count

Tags: custom-post-types, count, columns

What i would like to do;

if there is one post in custom post type, it should show up in one full column of bootstrap.

|     post   |

If there are two posts, they should show up in two half column (one-half).

| post | post |

If there are three posts, the should show up in three third columns (one-third).

|post|post|post|

And then it starts again from beginning.

|post|post|post|

| post |

I thought, i can use count_post function, but its not working as i expect.

For rows im using elements from this post:

[Posts in Multiple Columns and Rows with one single loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175944/posts-in-multiple-columns-and-rows-with-one-single-loop)

This post was not really helpfull:
[Set div columns in a loop by post count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200039/set-div-columns-in-a-loop-by-post-count)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be customized for your situation but it should be helpful.

```
      <?php
  // Start the loop.
  $i = 0; while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  if ( $i == 1 ) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
  <?php elseif ( $i == 2 ) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <?php elseif ( $i == 3 ) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
  // Include the carousel template content.
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

  </div>

  <?php
  // End the loop.
  $i++; endwhile;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but it shows all posts and styles each differently. Like this one http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/